# Read XML element detail containing £ with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to read a filename from an XML element in Powershell then verify the file is at its suggested location but I'm having trouble when the filename contains a £ sign.

XML Example:

```
<Item>
    <FileName>12345 £17000.pdf</FileName>
</Item>
```

I'm using the following code to extract the list of FileName elements:

```
$fNames = (Select-Xml -Path $_.FullName -XPath "//FileName" | foreach {$_.Node.Innerxml} )
```

This does indeed get the element detail but the £ appears as an � (black diamond with a question mark in it) an as such, my file verification doesn't work. See below:

```
12345 �17000.pdf
```

I'm sure its a simple solution but my searches have been unsuccessful so any assistance greatly appreciated.

---  Workaround ---

I've changed the code (using some of the example from TessellatingHeckler) from:

```
$fNames = (Select-Xml -Path $_.FullName -XPath "//FileName" | foreach {$_.Node.Innerxml} )
```

to

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $_
$fNames = (Select-Xml -Xml ([xml]$xml) -XPath "//FileName" | foreach {$_.Node.Innerxml} )
```

Rgds, Rob.

Comment: Works for me, if I `$x = '<Item><FileName>12345 £17000.pdf</FileName></Item>'; $fname = select-xml -Xml ([xml]$x) -XPath "//FileName" |% {$_.Node.InnerXml};"hi" | set-content $fname;test-path $fname` - to create a file with a pound sign the name and test it exists, from the xml fragment you gave - in PowerShell and ISE. The black diamond says "character encoding issue" and `£` is not an ASCII character. Where do you get the XML, and what kind of encoding is the XML content in?

Comment: As @TessellatingHeckler pointed out, it looks like a [mcve] works as we would expect for us.  Can you provide the XML header/data as well?  What about your OS installation - is it a different country, or maybe a different keyboard layout?  Finally, what's the `PSVersion` listed when you do a `$PSVersionTable` in PowerShell?

Comment: Thanks for the responses Guys.  The XML file is generated automatically with no header information at all, would this default to a particular type of encoding?  Strange that the issue happens on both the server I'm running it from Win2k8R2 PS v3.0 and also my workstation Win10 PS v5.0.10586.122.  Did the XML you created to test contain a properly formatted header?

Comment: I've also just tried the one liner code specified by @TessellatingHeckler and this works for me.  Looking like encoding of the XML file as suggested.  I can read the contents of a file using a particular form of encoding but am I also able to apply that to a select-xml ?

Comment: @RobBerry the encoding is up to the program doing the exporting; it might have picked something as a 'default' but that could still be a default for the program, or taken from the user settings or system-wide settings, or a platform default from its environment. If you say what it is, someone might know. If it's not too big a file, you might be able to `$data = [xml](get-content $fileName -Encoding 'whatever')` to read from the file using a specific encoding, then convert to XML, then use `Select-Xml` on that `$data`.

Comment: I've solved the issue I was having by changing the way that the select-xml works.  Instead of using -Path to reference the XML file, I've used Get-Content for the XML file then as part of the Select-XML I've referenced the variable using the code from @TessellatingHeckler (select-xml -XML ([xml]$xml) ) and things are working fine.  Thanks for the assistance. Rob.

Comment: Only just seen your comment TessellatingHeckler.  Thanks very much for your assistance.  Working as you suggest.  Kind Regards,Rob.